# Solution with vs2005 and vs2010 projects.Any problems

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I am currently working in a place where they still use .net 2.0.
I would like to add some projects(. net 4.0) to existing solution .

Would this create any issues?

I suppose as long I use a "top down approach " I should be fine no?

Is there something that I am missing that could cause issues?

Comment: There are many articles about what could go wrong when you change from .net 2.0 to higher one. Just use google for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is isolated from previous versions, so you will have to add a setting to your app.config so 4 can see the other versions.

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

I have one solution with five 2.0 projects and six 3.5 projects and one 4.0 project in Visual Studio 2010.

There were issues with the auto-generated designer code for Strongly-Typed DataSet classes that were fairly easy to resolve. I do suggest opening any entities that use designers so the auto-generated code is updated to Visual Studio 2010. This includes settings, resources, Windows.Form form/control classes, and so on.

Two other issues required updating to *Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010* and updating to *Visual Studio Tools for Office 3.0* for the projects that used Cystal Reports and Office.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem, but i recommend to change your project to 4.0 then add the others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using VS2010 as IDE No, this won't create any issue. Your .Net 2.0 projects will still be built against .Net framework 2 and similarly .Net 4 project will target .Net Framework 4.